# Strange behavior of RemoteObject after application built, no fault no result

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

When i run it in Flash Builder (debug mode) the remote object called successfully. but whenever i build the application (AIR application), then the remote object will return no result nor fault, the busy cursor is showing about 3 seconds. then no clue at all.

Any idea how to get advance fault or something than regular fault event or result event?
or anyone have the same experience?

**UPDATE:**

Actually it was failed only for ONE service method, for other method (some of them took longer time to call) the service call is work fine.

**CASE SOLVED**

So the problem was not on the service call, but on my result conversion that cause the advanced datagrid failed to render.

Best regards

ktutnik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a software like Charles to see what happens during the network call.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sadly it was an AIR application, really hard to find a good HTTP sniffer that showing good data format like APP Puncher etc. I tried to used WireShark, but i think need time to learn to use the tool. I tried charles, but i think it only work with browser, no?

Comment: yes its work, thanks, actually the Response Code is 200, Response Body returned is correct, but not trigger the remote object result.. any though to get a clue?